# Control Name for Insert tab

Tags: xml, excel, excel-2007, ms-office, vba

I am trying to design a workbook with some restrictions without using VBA in Excel, which is compatible in 2007 and 2010. I have chosen "Custom UI Editor For Microsoft Office" with XML code to restrict a few options:- Save-as with info tab, Insert, Delete, Move/Copy Sheet, Hide sheet, Unhide sheets. I was successful in doing so but I have noticed that insert sheet tab "ICON"

[image]

is still working and is accessible.  Can anyone point me to the Control Name to disable it through XML in file please?

My code is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <commands>
               <command idMso="FileSaveAsWebPage" enabled="false" />
               <command idMso="FileSaveAs" enabled="false" />
               <command idMso="FileSaveAsMenu" enabled="false" />
               <command idMso="FileSaveAsExcelXlsx" enabled="false" />
               <command idMso="FileSaveAsExcelXlsxMacro" enabled="false" />
               <command idMso="FileSaveAsExcel97_2003" enabled="false" />
               <command idMso="FileSaveAsExcelOpenDocumentSpreadsheet" enabled="false" />
               <command idMso="FileSaveAsPdfOrXps" enabled="false" />
               <command idMso="FileSaveAsOtherFormats" enabled="false" />

               <command idMso="SheetInsert" enabled="false" />
               <command idMso="SheetInsertPage" enabled="false" />
               <command idMso="SheetDelete" enabled="false" />
               <command idMso="SheetRename" enabled="false" />
               <command idMso="SheetMoveOrCopy" enabled="false" />
               <command idMso="SheetUnhide" enabled="false" />
               <command idMso="SheetProtect" enabled="false" />
               <command idMso="SheetTabColorGallery" enabled="false" /> 
               <command idMso="SheetTabColorMoreColorsDialog" enabled="false" />
             <command idMso="SelectAllSheets" enabled="false" />
  </commands>
  <backstage>
           <tab idMso="TabInfo" visible="false"/>
  </backstage>
</customUI>
```

I have tried searching Microsoft and [rondebruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm) for Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers also.

Comment: You can find all 2010 `idMso`s [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627)

Comment: Thank you Mehow for quick responce, Yes i have a copy of the same, i have tried using control named "SheetInsertPage" (as mentioned in the above code) still i am not able to make it disable. can you suggest me more

Comment: you cannot disable that tab

Comment: Any chances of disabling it by XML

Comment: Try `ReviewProtectWorkbook` maybe?

Comment: Jimson, as @pnuts says, Excel has pretty good built-in properties to restrict usage and 'editability' including preventing adding a new worksheet. An alternative, if necessary, to capture other scenarios beyond the built-in options is to hook in to the relevant Event and cancel it or undo it (e.g. you can register for the Worbook_NewSheet event and delete the new sheet)

Comment: Thanks Cor_Blimey, the aim was to not use any VBA, For the reason i have opted for XML as alternative.

Answer (score 5):

For this to be done through XML you would need to be able to access the element - it needs to have an ID. Manually scanning through the various lists that Microsoft published turned up nothing helpful, but since their documentation is notoriously sloppy I decided to write a very small piece of code that finds the ID of "every control with an ID" in the Excel application, and lists it:

```
Sub listID()
Dim r As Range
Dim ctls
Dim ii As Long

Cells(1, 1).Value = "ID"
Cells(1, 2).Value = "caption"
Cells(1, 3) = "Type"
Set r = Range("a1")

For ii = 1 To 100000
  Set ctls = CommandBars.FindControl(Id:=ii)
  If Not (ctls Is Nothing) Then
  'Debug.Print "controls ID " & ii & " exists; the caption is " & ctls.Caption & "; the type is " & ctls.Type
  Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
  r.Value = ii
  r.Offset(0, 1) = ctls.Caption
  r.Offset(0, 2) = ctls.Type
  r.Offset(0, 3) = ctls.TooltipText
  End If
Next ii

End Sub
```

After I run this, and filter on anything with `eet` in the name, I would expect to see all the controls "that can be controlled" (because they have an `msoID`) and that relate to "Sheets". The following is the snapshot of what this produces:

[image]

When I hover my mouse over the "button" you want to hide, I get the toolTip "Insert Sheet" - which isn't any of the ones I can see in my list. I conclude from this that it is indeed impossible to do what you are asking - you cannot disable that button with XML.

That doesn't mean you can't achieve what you would like. I would suggest the following approaches.

1. Trap the workbook event that is triggered when a new sheet is created, and delete it on the spot. When the button "stops working" people will soon give up.  Example code below.
2. Hide the sheet tabs completely, and provide an alternative method of navigating between sheets. Since this is obviously a "controlled spreadsheet" that may be a good idea anyway. You could either create a custom tab on the ribbon (using XML, you seem to be familiar with that), or create a floating toolbar that lives at the bottom of the sheet - close to where the "old" tabs used to be. In that way you simulate the behavior - but it's a lot of work and a bit of a hack
3. Add protection to the workbook. Use Protection -> Protect Workbook -> "Protect structure": `sheets can not be moved, deleted, hidden, unhidden, or renamed. New sheets cannot be inserted.`

The code you would have to add to `ThisWorkbook` is:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
  Dim temp As Boolean
  temp = Application.DisplayAlerts
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Sh.Delete
  Application.DisplayAlerts = temp
End Sub
```

Once this is in your workbook, any time a user clicks the "new sheet" button there will be a very brief flash, but no new sheet is created. You could add a `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` but the brief flash remains...

Sorry I don't have better news for you.

Comment: Thanks Floris, But i am sorry to say that i am looking for a solution in XML only. The main aim is to restrict user without Macros; VBA. i have thought of using only through XML as this integrates into the file i share and thus leaving user with lesser and limited options. How ever i am very thank full for your efforts made to crack.Once more thank you very much Floris.

Comment: I realize you asked for XML only solution - I suspect (based on the above) it may not be possible. May I ask _why_ you don't want any VBA in the background, or protection of the workbook structure - either of which appears to solve the problem? I'm curious...

Comment: Most of my users are not aware of it. (Instead i would like to say that I have tried using protect; but my enthusiastic users break it and modify all the time). I tried VBA where in many cases i found that, if security is not disabled/allowed; then aim is lost.After a through search i came up with xml which is more secure (based on the resources & conditions of my users).

Comment: Hope i have explained in a proper narration. Sorry for not being good at English vocabulary. And thanks for asking me more about the environments and Conditions. Please suggest me more on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can either choose the Review tab, choose Protect Workbook, and check Structure. You do not need to specify a password and the Insert Worksheet button will be disabled (but still visible).

Or you can go to the Excel Options from the Office Button, the Advanced tab, scroll down to **Display options for this workbook** and uncheck **Show sheet tabs**.

I do not believe that this can be done from XML. That is, to disable or hide this button (without hiding all the sheet tabs). Perhaps someone might prove me wrong ;)

Comment: I wouldn't be upset if someone proved me wrong ;) but I feel pretty confident, as it is an integral part of the UI.

Comment: I still believe that it can be achieved. A dark side is left which is left unexplored. i would let you know once i come across.

Comment: .. try not to let it disturb your sleep ;)

Comment: Thanks Andy, I will try, any how it has costed me 2 sleep less nights. I will still see to work around. Still i believe there is a Hope.. Thank you once again for sparing me with your valuable time and inputs.

Comment: I've asked *elsewhere* and if I get a response I'll let you know. (These are the guys - if they say yes or no then we can take it as gospel.)

Comment: Thanks Andy, i will wait.. Thank you once again.

Comment: My colleague (an MVP) doesn't believe it is possible either, using Custom UI, so I shall stick with my original answer ;)