# What is the idMso (Name) of the 'new sheet ' + Sign , on the Excel taskbar?

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

I need to know the **idMso** (Name) of the 'new sheet' **+** Sign on the Excel taskbar.

**Purpose:** User click by mistake this **+** Sign and create a lot of new sheets.

All the available methods depend on deleting the newly created sheet or making it very hidden.

I want to use **OfficeRibbonXEditor** to disable this control (only in that workbook).

I found these idMso **SheetInsert** and  **SheetInsertPage**. They only disable the **insert sheet** button (found on Home Tab).

[image]

Comment: You can't do that, I'm afraid. It doesn't have an idMso as it isn't on the ribbon.

Comment: Why don't you simply protect the workbook structure, it would stop users from creating, moving, renaming and deleting worksheets?

Comment: It is probably somewhere in the CommandBars collection, though I have no clue where or what it would be called.

Comment: @Vincent G ,sure I tried this option. <br>
But this raised another problems, as my workbook has a lot of sheets (very hidden) . <br>
and there are macro assigned to show `make visible` the desired sheet. <br>
<b>These macro does not work when the structure of workbook is protected</b>. <br>

Comment: Did you read this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17899655/16578424 - this would be another solution to the one I provided

Comment: @Ike ,Thanks for your keen help, I opened your provided link and I got two new
**ID** (Not idmso) **18 ,with caption &New...** and ID  957 with Caption Sheet1**
`But` really I do not know how to use with ` OfficeRibbonXEditor` or even in vba code,
**Please** point me if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

As you already need macros for unhiding sheets you could unprotect the workbook temporarily as well:

```vb
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Private Const pwd As String = "test"  '<--- adjust this to your needs

Public Sub unhideSheet(ws As Worksheet)
unlockWorkbook
   ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
lockWorkbook
End Sub

Public Sub hideSheet(ws As Worksheet)
unlockWorkbook
   ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
lockWorkbook
End Sub


Private Sub lockWorkbook()
ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:=pwd, Structure:=True, Windows:=False
End Sub

Private Sub unlockWorkbook()
ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:=pwd
End Sub
```

Moreover you could call `lockWorkbook` from the `Workbook_Open` and `Workbook_BeforeClose` events to be on the safe side.

Comment: But , this a different approach, I already know. I need to disable the button itself.

Comment: The button is disabled when the workbook is protected. It is visible (greyed out) - but you can't click it.

Comment: Unfortunately, my workbook is shared and protected, So your answer is not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that. The best what you could do is to try using Windows API functions to subclass the Excel windows. Read more about the Ribbon UI in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0):

I would just capture Workbook NewSheet event like this:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets(Sh.Name).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End Sub
```